# Python - Versioned list instead of immutable list?

Tags: python, list

*Update:*

- As of CPython 3.6, dictionaries have a version (thank you [pylang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531270/pylang) for showing this to me).
- If they added the same *version* to list and made it public, *all 3 asserts from my original post would pass!* It would definitely meet my needs. Their implementation differs from what I envisioned, but I like it.
- As it is, I don't feel I can use dictionary version:

  - It isn't public. Jake Vanderplas shows how to expose it in a [post](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/05/26/exposing-private-dict-version/), but he cautions: *definitely not code you should use for any purpose beyond simply having fun*. I agree with his reasons.
  - In all of my use cases, the data is conceptually arrays of elements each of which has the same structure. A list of tuples is a natural fit. Using a dictionary would make the code less natural and probably more cumbersome.
- Does anyone know if there are plans to add version to list?
- Are there plans to make it public?

If there are plans to add *version* to list and make it public, I would feel awkward putting forward an incompatible VersionedList now. I would just implement the bare minimum I need and get by.

---

*Original post below*

---

Turns out that many of the times I wanted an immutable list, a *VersionedList* would have worked almost as well (sometimes even better).

- Has anyone implemented a versioned list?
- Is there a better, more Pythonic, concept that meets my needs? (See motivation below.)

What I mean by a versioned list is:

- A class that behaves like a list
- Any change to an instance or elements in the instance results in `instance.version()` being updated. So, if `alist` is a normal list:

  ```
  a = VersionedList(alist)
  a_version = a.version()
  change(a)
  assert a_version != a.version()
  reverse_last_change(a)
  ```
- If a list was hashable, hash() would achieve the above and meet all the needs identified in the motivation below. We need to define 'version()' in a way that doesn't have *all* of the same problems as 'hash()'.

  If identical data in two lists is highly unlikely to ever happen except at initialization, we aren't going to have a reason to test for deep equality. From ([https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__))  *The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value*. If we don't impose this requirement on 'version()', it seems likely that 'version()' won't have all of the same problems that makes lists unhashable. So unlike hash, identical contents *doesn't* mean the same version

  ```
  #contents of 'a' are now identical to original, but...
  assert a_version != a.version()

  b = VersionedList(alist)
  c = VersionedList(alist)
  assert b.version() != c.version()
  ```
- For VersionList, it would be good if any attempt to modify the result of `__get__` automatically resulted in a copy instead of modifying the underlying implementation data. I think that the only other option would be to have `__get__` always return a copy of the elements, and this would be very inefficient for all of the use cases I can think of. I think we need to restrict the elements to immutable objects (deeply immutable, for example: exclude tuples with list elements). I can think of 3 ways to achieve this:

  1. Only allow elements that can't contain mutable elements (int, str, etc are fine, but exclude tuples). *(This is far too limiting for my cases)*
  2. Add code to `__init__`, `__set__`, etc to traverse inputs to deeply check for mutable sub-elements. *(expensive, any way to avoid this?)*
  3. Also allow more complex elements, but require that they are deeply immutable. Perhaps require that they expose a `deeply_immutable` attribute. *(This turns out to be easy for all the use cases I have)*

Motivation:

1. If I am analyzing a dataset, I often have to perform multiple steps that return large datasets (note: since the dataset is *ordered*, it is best represented by a List not a set).

   If at the end of several steps (ex: 5) it turns out that I need to perform different analysis (ex: back at step 4), I want to know that the dataset from step 3 hasn't accidentally been changed. That way I can start at step 4 instead of repeating steps 1-3.
2. I have functions (control-points, first-derivative, second-derivative, offset, outline, etc) that depend on and return array-valued objects (in the linear algebra sense). The base 'array' is `knots`.

   `control-points()` *depends on:* `knots`, `algorithm_enum`
   `first-derivative()` *depends on:* `control-points()`, `knots`
   `offset()` *depends on:* `first-derivative()`, `control-points()`, `knots`, `offset_distance`
   `outline()` *depends on:* `offset()`, `end_type_enum`

   If `offset_distance` changes, I want to avoid having to recalculate first-derivative() and control-points(). To avoid recalculation, I need to know that nothing has accidentally changed the resultant 'arrays'.

   If 'knots' changes, I need to recalculate everything and not depend on the previous resultant 'arrays'.

   To achieve this, `knots` and all of the 'array-valued' objects could be VersionedList.

FYI: I had hoped to take advantage of an efficient class like numpy.ndarray. In most of my use cases, the elements logically have structure. Having to mentally keep track of multi-dimensions of indexes meant implementing and debugging the algorithms was many times more difficult with ndarray. An implementation based on lists of namedtuples of namedtuples turned out to be much more sustainable.

Comment: Can you clarify that last block of code? It's not valid Python. Show us the code you'd use exactly as you envision using it.

Comment: What is `knots[]` suppose to be? That looks like you are trying to declare `knots` as an array, but there are no variable declarations in Python, and you probably mean for it to be a list, not an array... But you *do* mention arrays, but what exactly do you mean? `array.array`? `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: In the actual implementation, all of the arrays are members of the object. This makes it easy to have independent instances. So, the calls have empty argument lists. The actual code would have to include a large section of a large class in order to illuminate the dependencies.

Comment: See the edit to my comment, *what do you mean by array*.

Comment: I've done that with `dict` in the past and the solution is to have a 'deleted' element to denote deleted keys, and store updated keys in each new version as separate `dicts`, then do deep-tree flattening to get the current version. With lists it's more complex as you need to keep the order and relation as well, and not only on one level - this will quickly get you to realize that you'll either need to build a state machine (CPU intensive) or create a new copy for each destructive change to the original list (memory intensive). Given these problems, I doubt the utility of such a structure.

Comment: To [zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7553525/zwer), definitely want to avoid a state machine. Since my actual use cases have immutable elements, I haven't had to make a deep copy. So far it looks like carefully implemented `__init__`, `__set__`, etc. will be enough. Since the elements are immutable, any attempt to modify something returned by `__get__` automatically results in a copy instead of modifying the underlying list. I am probably missing something.

Comment: Are you using NumPy? If so and you just want to make sure nothing changed "accidentally", just make your array "readonly": `yourarray.flags.writeable = False`. But I guess I'm missing the point of the question...

Answer (score 1):

**Private dicts in 3.6**

In Python 3.6, dictionaries are now private ([PEP 509](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0509/)) and compact ([issue 27350](https://bugs.python.org/issue27350)), which track versions and preserve order respectively.  These features are presently true when using the CPython 3.6 implementation.  Despite the challenge, Jake VanderPlas demonstrates in his [blog post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/05/26/exposing-private-dict-version/#Exploring-the-Version-Number) a detailed demonstration of exposing this versioning feature from CPython within normal Python.  We can use his approach to:

1. determine when a dictionary has been updated
2. preserve the order

Example

```
import numpy as np

d = {"a": np.array([1,2,3]),
     "c": np.array([1,2,3]),
     "b": np.array([8,9,10]),
    }

for i in range(3):
    print(d.get_version())                                 # monkey-patch
# 524938
# 524938
# 524938
```

Notice the version number does not change until the dictionary is updated, as shown below:

```
d.update({"c": np.array([10, 11, 12])})
d.get_version()
# 534448
```

In addition, the insertion order is preserved (the following was tested in restarted sessions of Python 3.5 and 3.6):

```
list(d.keys())
# ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

You may be able to take advantage of this new dictionary behavior, saving you from implementing a new datatype.

---

**Details**

For those interested, the latter `get_version()`is a monkey-patched method for any dictionary, implemented in Python 3.6 using the following modified code derived from Jake VanderPlas' blog post.  This code was run prior to calling `get_version().`

```
import types
import ctypes
import sys
assert (3, 6) <= sys.version_info < (3, 7)                 # valid only in Python 3.6

py_ssize_t = ctypes.c_ssize_t  

# Emulate the PyObjectStruct from CPython
class PyObjectStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ob_refcnt', py_ssize_t),
                ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p)]


# Create a DictStruct class to wrap existing dictionaries
class DictStruct(PyObjectStruct):
    _fields_ = [("ma_used", py_ssize_t),
                ("ma_version_tag", ctypes.c_uint64),
                ("ma_keys", ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("ma_values", ctypes.c_void_p),
               ]

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"DictStruct(size={self.ma_used}, "
                f"refcount={self.ob_refcnt}, "
                f"version={self.ma_version_tag})")

    @classmethod
    def wrap(cls, obj):
        assert isinstance(obj, dict)
        return cls.from_address(id(obj))

assert object.__basicsize__ == ctypes.sizeof(PyObjectStruct)
assert dict.__basicsize__ == ctypes.sizeof(DictStruct)


# Code for monkey-patching existing dictionaries
class MappingProxyStruct(PyObjectStruct):
    _fields_ = [("mapping", ctypes.POINTER(DictStruct))]

    @classmethod
    def wrap(cls, D):
        assert isinstance(D, types.MappingProxyType)
        return cls.from_address(id(D))

assert types.MappingProxyType.__basicsize__ == ctypes.sizeof(MappingProxyStruct)


def mappingproxy_setitem(obj, key, val):
    """Set an item in a read-only mapping proxy"""
    proxy = MappingProxyStruct.wrap(obj)
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyDict_SetItem(proxy.mapping,
                                    ctypes.py_object(key),
                                    ctypes.py_object(val))

mappingproxy_setitem(dict.__dict__,
                     'get_version',
                     lambda self: DictStruct.wrap(self).ma_version_tag)
```

Comment: Thank you [pylang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4531270/pylang), this is very exiting. I don't think I can use it for my projects since [Jake Vanderplas' post states:](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/05/26/exposing-private-dict-version/) *definitely not code you should use for any purpose beyond simply having fun*, and his reasons for saying this are compelling.

Comment: The CPython implementation should certainly be applied provisonally since it is quite new. Whether this will become public for dicts in future versions or applied to lists is speculative at the moment.   As for Python 3.6, it should work albeit avant-garde.